# Symfony 2 Error: Call to a member function andWhere() on array

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, for-loop, query-builder

I'm trying to execute a QueryBuilder query, but it doesn't like the "andWhere" syntax in the for loop. I don't think it likes anything in the for loop. It's supposed to check if any of the array elements equals "x" so that it filters the search results based on that.

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Shrubs');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');

$shrubs = $query
    ->where($query->expr()->like('p.botanicalname', ':botanicalname'))
    ->setParameter('botanicalname', '%' . $botanicalname . '%')
    ->andwhere($query->expr()->like('p.commonname', ':commonname'))
    ->setParameter('commonname', '%' . $commonname . '%')
    ->orderBy('p.commonname', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

$checkfor = array("wetsoil"=>"Tolerates Wet Soil",
    "borderlinehardy"=>"Borderline Hardy",
    "moistsoil"=>"Prefers Moist Soil";

reset($checkfor);

foreach ($checkfor as $key => $value) {
    if (${$key} == "x") {
        $shrubs = $shrubs->andWhere('$key = x')
            ->setParameter('x', $key)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        return $this->render('shrubs/searchresults.html.twig', array(
            'shrubs' => $shrubs,));
    }
}

return $this->render('shrubs/searchresults.html.twig', array(
    'shrubs' => $shrubs
```

Comment: Don't run getQuery()->getResult() before/in your foreach.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$shrubs` variable is the `$query` result, you call `->getQuery()->getResult()`

Your code fixed would look like

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Shrubs');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');

$query
    ->where($query->expr()->like('p.botanicalname', ':botanicalname'))
    ->setParameter('botanicalname', '%' . $botanicalname . '%')
    ->andwhere($query->expr()->like('p.commonname', ':commonname'))
    ->setParameter('commonname', '%' . $commonname . '%')
    ->orderBy('p.commonname', 'ASC')
    ; // Remove ->getQuery() and->getResult()

$checkfor = array("wetsoil"=>"Tolerates Wet Soil",
    "borderlinehardy"=>"Borderline Hardy",
    "moistsoil"=>"Prefers Moist Soil";

reset($checkfor);

foreach ($checkfor as $key => $value) {
    if (${$key} == "x") {
        $shrubs = $query->andWhere('$key = x')
            ->setParameter('x', $key)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
        return $this->render('shrubs/searchresults.html.twig', array(
            'shrubs' => $shrubs,));
    }
}

$shrubs = $query->getQuery()->getResult();// Execute the query here

return $this->render('shrubs/searchresults.html.twig', array(
    'shrubs' => $shrubs
);
```

Comment: It says: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 120: Error: Expected Literal, got '$'". Seems like we're getting closer...

Comment: The error is for the line `$query->andWhere('$key = x')`, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but if `$key`is supposed to be a column name, you should write `$key->andWhere('p.' . $key' = :x')` (you have forgotten the `:`too)

Comment: And (${$key} == "x") is not going to help either.  The whole foreach loop makes no sense.  If you just want to filter the shrubs then use array_filter.

Comment: I still don't get any search results, but that resolved my error. Thanks! I'll research array_filter now. Much appreciated!